# How to change Project Theme Dynamically in Aurelia

Tags: css, themes, aurelia, saas

I want to change my project theme dynamically.I created different themes files like as "Blue",Red","Light","Black" etc .As my Given code below "light-theme.scss" is my theme file which I am requiring in App.html above from "ezmax-home-pages.scss" which is main file.

Basically light-theme file is importing in main file and changeing project theme.Its working for me .But there are many theme files.I cant change theme file path manually every time.

I google and find many solutions but none of those worked.I found that you cant use any variable in require tag etc Kindly tell is there any solution for my problem.

```
 <require from="./assets/css/light-theme.scss"></require>
  <require from="./assets/css/ezmax-home-pages.scss"></require>
```

Light theme

```
:root {
    --themeColor: #007ACC;
    --otherButtonColor: #26a69a;
    --cancelButtonColor: rgb(244, 67, 54);
    --themeBackColor: #F5F5F5;
    --themeElementColor: #fff;
    --themeAltColor: #f8fafb;
    --themeNormalColor: #fff;
    --themetxtColor: #000;
    --themeAlttxtColor: #8997a6;
    --themeDarkBorderColor: #D7D7DB;
    --themeBorderColor: #e8eaed;
    --themeDarkAltColor: #f0f4f6;
  }
```

I want to make dynamic approach where i can change theme file path by selecting theme file name from drop-down like and code will change path of my theme file and project theme change dynamically.

Comment: Aamir, I think that a solution to this issue depends on which bundling scheme you are using. I have an app built with aurelia and for every customer we totally personalize the theme with a css; then, in the initialization of app I write the correct css src attribute on the dom.

Comment: What prompted you to delete the old issue and create a new one?

Comment: Respected Cristián Ormazábal ,We are using WebPack Scheme for project.IN my scenario every user have its own custom theme which he will saved or choosed.Kindly tell me how i can handle this on App initialization for correct css src attribute on the dom.

Comment: Respected Alex Dresko ,I thought my old question was not clear to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aamir. In your case, as you have webpack for bundling, you'd have to manage users stylesheets separate from the source code. If not, with every new customer you'd be forced to recompile and publish.
A solution is to have a repository with customers's stylesheets and build something like this:

```
themes = [
    {
      title: "default",
      url:
        "https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    },
    {
      title: "cerulean",
      url: "https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css"
    },
    {
      title: 'darkly',
      url: 'https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.min.css'
    }
  ];

activate() {
    this.changeTheme(this.themes[0]);
}
changeTheme(theme) {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    const itemId = 'css-sheet';
    let link = document.getElementById(itemId);
    if (!link) {
      link = document.createElement("link");
      link.id = itemId;
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.type = "text/css";
      link.href = theme.url;  <-- here occurs the switch
      link.media = "all";
      head.appendChild(link);
    } else {
      link.href = theme.url;
    }
}
```

This example works by choosing the theme from a dropdown menu. In your case, the url of the sheet should be inferred from the customer's profile.

A working example with external stylesheets is available on the following link https://codesandbox.io/s/aurelia-dynamic-css-enrge?fontsize=14.

Wish you the best.

Comment: Yes That's the same output i was expecting .Thanks Sir.